# Always log off from your Facebook account

Tags: story, cipher

It began with a normal Saturday afternoon. Judy, driving off in a rush from the garage, forgot to log off from her Facebook account on the computer. Her husband Andrew took the chance to scan through Judy's messages. He found a strange conversation that seems to have happened just a while ago:

```
Bob:     2zfd hlj vfdd gl kbng
Judy:    4twa
Bob:     6o nppl s jpyr;
Judy:    8o35[w yqf3 r7h
```

Frustrated, he saved the message to study later and shut down the computer so Judy wouldn't know he checked her messages.

Two weeks later, Andrew got a chance to gain access to Judy's Facebook account again when she rushed to the bathroom with diarrhea. He opened up the messenger and sent Bob the following:

```
"6O S, [TRHMSMY"
```

Soon after that evening, Bob was found dead in his apartment from a heart attack.

***Can you tell what is happening in the story, and more important, what's in the message?***

Comment: Interesting cipher.  But I downvoted because I found the story a bit disturbing.  Sorry.

Comment: The moral of the story: Don't do the crime if you can't do the time!

Comment: @KeyboardWielder I'm not certain personal feelings justifies a down vote.

Comment: @Zymus You can discuss it, but that's all you can. Voting is subjective, and is a matter of choice, unless a clear misbehaviour is going on :-)

Comment: Thanks for all the support!  As for KeyboardWielder, my apologize you found it disturbing, hopefully it's not mirroring something happened in real life.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1st dialog:

> Bob: are you free to**n**ight *(space is ambiguous here for **n**)*
>  Judy: yes
>  Bob: i book a hotel
>  Judy: let's have fun

Andrew's message:

> I AM PREGNANT

Explanation:

> First digit indicates which neighbor key to look on the keyboard for the message: 2 = up, 4 = right, 6 = left, 8 = down. The opposite direction is used for encoding - the same as in numeric keypad.

And answer to the question:

> The story is contained in the messages... I think no more details are needed ;)

Comment: Nicely done!  Hope this cipher puzzle isn't too easy for ya

Comment: @Alex Thanks! It wouldn't be easy if looked only from deciphering point of view - in fact there are 4 different substitution ciphers. I think thoughts of what practically can be used for real-time ciphering a message using keyboard helped me a lot :)

Comment: Hahahahahhhhahahhahahahahaaaa this post deserves a legendary status Hahahahahaaa